# Why does equation $a · x = 0$ always has $n − 1$ linearly independent solutions for $x$ and never has $n$ linearly independent solutions?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis, vector-spaces

For any nonzero vector $a ∈ \mathbb{R}^n$, why is it that the equation $a · x = 0$ always has $n − 1$ linearly independent solutions for $x$ and never has $n$ linearly independent solutions?

My progress so far is that I can prove that the set of vectors $a_1, . . . , a_m$ cannot be linearly independent in $\mathbb{R}^n$ if $m > n$.

Comment: You have asked two questions, and in each one you tell us you have solved the other one.

Comment: Hint: Use the rank-nullity theorem and the fact that $x \mapsto \langle a, x\rangle$ is a linear functional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can have $n$ independent solutions if $a=0$, and *only* in that case.

Indeed, if this equation has $n$ linearly independent solutions,  these solutions are a *basis* of $\mathbf R^n$. Thus $a\cdot x=0$ for all $x$ in a basis, hence it is $0$ for all $x\in\mathbf R^n $, in particular for $x=a$. There results that $\;a\cdot a=\lVert a\rVert^2=0$, which implies $a=0$ (if $a=(a_1,\dots,a_n)$, $\lVert a\rVert^2=a_1^2+\dots+a_n^2$ is a sum of squares, and if a sum of squares is $0$, each square is $0$).

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: The question says _nonzero_ $a$.

Comment: Then the O.P. is not mistaken (which was only a way of speaking).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that the equation $a \cdot x$ did have $n$ linearly independent solutions. Arrange them into the columns of a matrix $X$. Then we have that $a \cdot X = 0$. But since X consists of n linearly independent columns we know that X is invertible and so by multiplying by $X^{-1}$ on both sides gives us that $a=0$, contrary to our assumption.

In addition, since $a \neq 0$ we can extend $a$ to an orthogonal basis $\{a,x_1..., x_{n-1}\}$. By definition of an orthogonal basis, $\{x_1..., x_{n-1}\}$ are linearly independent and $a \cdot x_i = 0$.